# calculation of p and q factor in a given table

Tags: r

I have table of soil moisture deficit (SMD) table with 170 column (each column is a month) and 103937 rows and I want to calculate the p and q as in equation below, I wrote a code but it *does not work from fourth line*; it says:

> error in vector(length=21,na.rm=TRUE is unused arguments)

there are many NA in the data which I don’t want to include:equation is

```
    p=1-(m/m+b)....1
    q=C/(m+b)......2
```

Where m and b are the slope and intercept of the linear regression between the cumulative SMD in driest and wettest conditions vs different durations from one month to eighteen months (Figure 9). For each grid cell, to evaluate m and b in dry conditions, the driest month in the history (lowest SMD) was first selected and plotted for one-month duration. Then the running sums of SMD for every two neighboring months were calculated and the lowest cumulative SMD was selected as well for two-month duration. Same process repeated until eighteen-month duration and highest cumulative SMD was chosen for wet conditions. Then a linear regression was used to fit these plots and identify the slope,-m and intercept, b. C is from the best-fit line of a drought monograph to scale, which ranges from -100 to 100 which is then scaled to fit the range of PDSI categories (-4, 4). The code is as follows:

```
SM=read.table('SMD.csv',header=T,sep=',')
df=data.frame(data[3:21])#subset from 3 to 21 column; i have 2000 column and 103937rows.
matrix=data.matrix(df)
x=t(t(c(matrix[3:21])))
dry=vector(Length=21, na.rm=TRUE)
wet=vector(length= 21,na.rm=TRUE )
 slope_dry= vector(length= 103937,na.rm=TRUE )
 slope_wet= vector(length= 103937,na.rm=TRUE )
 inter_dry= vector(length= 103937,na.rm=TRUE )
 inter_wet= vector(length= 103937,na.rm=TRUE )

 for (a in 1:103937){
    for (i in 1:103937) {
       sum_SMD=vector(length=nrow(matrix)-i+1)
       for (j in 1 : (nrow(matrix)-i+1)) {
           for(b in j :(j+i-1))
       sum_SMD[j]<-sum_SMD[j]+SMD[b,a]
       }
       dry[i]<-min(sum_SMD)
       wet[i]<-max(sum_SMD)

       }
       model_dry<-lm(dry~x)
          slope_dry[a]<-coefficients(model_dry)[2]
          inter_dry[a]<-coefficients(model_dry)[1]
       model_wet<-lm(wet~x)
          slope_wet[a]<-coefficients(model_wet)[2]
          inter_wet[a]<-coefficients(model_wet)[1]
       }

  c_dry=slope_dry/25
   #c_dry=-4
   p_dry=1-slope_dry/(slope_dry+inter_dry)
   q_dry=c_dry/(slope_dry+inter_dry)

   #c_wet=4
  c_wet=slope_wet/25
   p_wet=1-slope_wet/(slope_wet+inter_wet)
   q_wet=c_wet/(slope_wet+inter_wet)
```

Comment: No argument `na.rm` in `vector()` function. Check `?vector`. You need to take care of `NAs` in some other way....

Comment: You could remove the `NAs` from the main dataframe, `df` itself.

Comment: Manoj G  thanks but,                                                         It doesnot work, i revomed all NAs and run the code but it still stucks in fourth line with same error;Error in vector(Length = 18) : unused argument (Length = 18).Juvin

Comment: `vector(length=18)` and `vector(length = 18, mode ="numeric")` working fine for me. `L` should be lower case. In the above error, it is upper case. R is case sensitive.

Comment: In your question also, `L` in `length` (line no:5 in code) is upper case. It should not be.